# I'm trying to come up with a shell script to rename a file and run a command each time the filename changes

Tags: bash, shell, sh

How do I make the below a shell script that changes a .txt filename and executes a golang script after each name change, taking the new .txt file as an argument.

NB: my txt file is in a different directory hence the path and they both cannot be in the same directory.

I want to execute this 50 times for each new txt file, with filename changing from t1 to t50 each time, without having to make 50 copies of the txt file.

`cd /home/rundeck; mv a.txt a1.txt; cd /home/jenkins/script; ./test.go /home/rundeck/a1.txt`

`cd /home/rundeck; mv a1.txt a2.txt; cd /home/jenkins/script; ./test.go /home/rundeck/a2.txt`

`cd /home/rundeck; mv a2.txt a3.txt; cd /home/jenkins/script; ./test.go /home/rundeck/a3.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```sh
#!/bin/bash
d=/home/rundeck
cd /home/jenkins/script
src="a.txt"
for ((i=1; i<=50; ++i)); do
    dst="a$i.txt"
    mv "$d/$src" "$d/$dst"
    ./test.go "$d/$dst"
    src=$dst
done
mv "$d/$dst" "$d"/a.txt
```

Perhaps it would make sense to copy `a.txt` in each iteration instead of successively renaming it, then remove the last file when you are done instead; that makes the script more robust against interruptions.

Comment: Works! thanks! Third line from bottom should be src=$dst

Comment: Thanks for the fix, and sorry for such a stupid typo!